# Does the $\text{CNOT}$ gate activate if the control qubit is $-|1⟩?$

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-circuit

I understand how the $\text{CNOT}$ gate works intuitively:

[image]

However, say we have a circuit where the $Z$ gate is applied to $|1⟩$, which turns $|1⟩ \to -|1⟩$. Then, there is a $\text{CNOT}$ gate with the control being $-|1⟩$ and the target $|0⟩$. What would the output look like? Would the $\text{CNOT}$ gate work in its usual way and give $-|1⟩|0⟩ \to -|1⟩|1⟩$ as the output?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Think of the $-|1\rangle$ state as a superposition of basis states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ (albeit a weird one). In this case, you can apply the general rule for the CNOT gate acting on superpositions: apply the gate to each basis state separately, and the result is the linear combination of results of applying the gate to the basis states.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would. It is sometimes better to think in the vector-matrix representation than in the dirac notations.

$$|1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
 0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Now,

$$Z|1\rangle = -|1\rangle =\begin{bmatrix}
 0\\ 
-1
\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Now,

$$-|1\rangle \otimes |0\rangle =\begin{bmatrix}
 0\\ 
-1
\end{bmatrix} \otimes \begin{bmatrix}
 1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0\\ 
0 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}   \,.$$

Applying $\text{CNOT}$,

$$\text{CNOT}\left(-|1\rangle \otimes |0\rangle \right) = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0& 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0  & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 0\\ 
0 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}  =  \begin{bmatrix}
 0\\ 
0 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}   = -|1\rangle \otimes |1\rangle \equiv |1\rangle \otimes -|1\rangle\,.$$